# Query user profiles depend on custom property in sharepoint 2010

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I want to query user profiles in sharepoint 2010 which depend on custom a field in the user profile without needing to iterate on every user profile in sharepoint. How can i do this?

For Example, I created new field in user profile called Account.

I want to retrieve all the user profiles with the same account name without needing to iterate to every user profile.

Comment: Do you mean the user profile from the site collection (user information list) or from central user profile DB which cames from "User Profile Service Application" ?

Answer (score 0):

Using caml query  you can get all  the user profiles with the same account name.

Hope this answer is very helpful for you.